How can I reshape an object to satisfy a complex interface without using type any?
I'm trying to change the shape of Item to meet a complex interface NewItem by calling transformData(). However I'm getting the following error.
The error message is "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'."  Here's a simplified version of my code that still produces the error:
interface Item {
  itemName: ItemName;
  quantity: number;
  itemBreakdown ? : [];
}

type ItemName = 'Dog' | 'Plant' | 'Unknown'

interface NewItem {
  animal: number;
  plant: number;
  food: number;
  unknown: number;
  itemBreakdown ? : {
    catergory1 ? : [ItemDetails]
    catergory2 ? : [ItemDetails]
  };
  error ? : Error | Error[]
}

private transformData(items: Item[]): NewItem {
  const newItem: NewItem = {};

  items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const { itemName, quantity } = item;
    // Error thrown by line below
    acc[this.mapItemName(itemName)] = quantity;
    return acc;
  }, newItem);

  return newItem;
}

private mapItemName(itemName: string): string {
  switch (itemName) {
    case 'Dog':
      return 'animal';
    case 'Plant':
      return 'plant';
    default:
      return 'unknown';
  }
}

TS7053: Element implicitly has an any type because expression of type string can't be used to index type NewItem
No index signature with a parameter of type string was found on type NewItem

I think I understand the issue but I'm not sure what's the right way to solve it.
The issue is that I'm passing in a key of type string to  {}: NewItem, where NewItem has no index signature of key[string] : number.
I can't assign key[string] : number to NewItem Interface because what about the other values?
I don't want to set type as any either or turn off strict mode.
What's the correct way to solve this without losing type safety?

What happens in your code when mapItemName() returns "unknown"? You can't set newItem.unknown, can you? So there's going to be an error unless you add unknown as a key to NewItem, as shown in this playground link. What exactly is the use case here? Can we assume that mapItemName() returns a value of type K, where NewItem is a sutbype of Record<K, number>? Or can we not assume that?

That’s what I thought I’m implying when the string mapItemName() returns matches the key of interface NewItem. eg, ‘animal’ is a key of NewItem.animal .

Where are you implying that? Given that mapItemName() can return "unknown", but NewItem doesn't have an unknown key, it's plainly not the case. It's worse that mapItemName() returns string, but even if we limit it to "animal" | "plant" | "unknown", I don't see anywhere you guarantee that it's not "unknown".  What am I missing?

ohhh alright sorry thats my mistake something thats missed when I simplifed the code for stackoverflow.
Okay Interface NewItem does contain key 'unknown'. So back to your first comment. Its safe to say mapItemName() returns a value of type K, where one of the property(not all property) is of type Record<K, number>.

Does this answer your question? Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index

So then all you have to do it not annotate the return type of mapItemName(), as shown here. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write an answer or find an existing question it duplicates. If not, what am I missing?

Thanks jcalz that solved it. Silly me all I had to do was not annotate it.

Your mapItemName should be of the type of keyof NewItem. Moreover we can map ItemName to a new type NewItemKey ensuring the result exists in NewItem's keys:
Playground
interface Item {
  itemName: ItemName;
  quantity: number;
  itemBreakdown ? : [];
}

type ItemName = 'Dog' | 'Plant' | 'Food' | 'Unknown';
type NewItemKey<T extends ItemName> = T extends 'Dog' ? 'animal' : T extends 'Plant' ? 'plant' : T extends 'Food' ? 'food' : 'unknown';

interface NewItem {
  animal: number;
  plant: number;
  food: number;
  unknown: number;
  itemBreakdown ? : {
    catergory1 ? : any[]
    catergory2 ? : any[]
  };
  error ? : Error | Error[]
}

class Reshape{

    private transformData(items: Item[]) {
        return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
            const { itemName, quantity } = item;
            acc[this.mapItemName(itemName)] = quantity;
            return acc;
        }, {} as NewItem);
    }

    private mapItemName(itemName: ItemName): NewItemKey<typeof itemName> {
        switch (itemName) {
            case 'Dog':
                return 'animal';
            case 'Plant':
                return 'plant';
            case 'Food':
                return 'food';
            default:
                return 'unknown'
        }
    }
}

But the whole construct isn't type safe, using {} as Newitem we skip required fields animal, plant, etc. Either make them optional or ensure that Item[] passed to transformData contains all items needed to fill NewItem properly (I guess that's not something trivial but achievable).

When I set the return type of mapItemName to keyof NewItem. It throws an error expecting it to account for the other value type of NewItem.

@ChunChan you shouldn't do that. the key is mapitemname should return an exact key based on item name so this exact key would infer the type of its value in newitem. otherwise you have a problem you came with

@ChunChan i'll prepare better solution with automating NewItemKey later

Silly me all I had to do was not to define a return type...
